# Configuring infinispan

Tags: infinispan, jgroups

My application is running on 10 servers and I use infinispan for managing the cache on those 10 servers. Currently infinispan is configured on all the 10 servers. I wish to restrict the infinispan instances to just 4 servers instead of the current 10. The number of servers is not changing and is remaining fixed at 10.

I am also wish to use JGroups, that is a part of infinispan package to replicate the cache data across the 4 infinispan instances.

Can someone help me to understand how it can be done.

Comment: How about using different cluster names? https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/8.2/apidocs/org/infinispan/configuration/global/TransportConfigurationBuilder.html#clusterName-java.lang.String-

Comment: what server and what version ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup multicast address on your jgroups xml configuration file (mcast_addr and mcast_port). Make sure your 4 server have the same multicast address and give different address for the other 6.